# Referencing in multienum package

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate

Can you reference the counter when using the `multienum` package? See MWE below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multienum}

\begin{document}

\begin{multienumerate}
\mitemxxx{Not\label{test1}}{Linear}{Not\label{test2}}
\end{multienumerate}
\ref{test1} \ref{test2}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently not.

The package adds 1 to counters explicitly in lots of places that it could have used `\refstepcounter`. Rather than find and patch them all, it's simpler just to have a top level command that resets the counter by 1 and then uses `\refstepcounter`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multienum}

\newcommand{\makerefable}{
\addtocounter{multienum\romannumeral\themultienumdepth}{-1}%
\refstepcounter{multienum\romannumeral\themultienumdepth}}

\begin{document}

\begin{multienumerate}
\mitemxxx{Not\makerefable\label{test1}}
{Linear}
{Not\makerefable\label{test2}}
\end{multienumerate}
\ref{test1} \ref{test2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are the definitely a TeX expert. Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain how you figured it out, like what the command does and what its part means and which part of the package you looked at to determine the solution?

Comment: @azetina well first I had to _get_ the package from ctan as it isn't in texlive then a quick look at the source showed that the number is printed by `\labelname` and adding `\show\labelname` produced `> \labelname=\long macro:
->\csname labelenum\romannumeral \themultienumdepth \endcsname .
` which is more or less the form I used in the macro to add -1 and then refstepcounter